# Identity Server / OWIN Single SignOut

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin, identityserver3

I have a question regarding this example:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L50

For my understanding, the user gets logged of on the `Signout()` method,
redirecting to Identity Server. There the server will logout all other client applications via an IFrame, including the one that initiated the logout.

This is what the  `SignoutCleanup(string sid)` method is for.
But as I already logged out, and the endpoint doesn't need authentication, my user will be null and there is no logout performed. Is this by design for the application that initiated the logout, or should the logout be performed only in  `SignoutCleanup(string sid)` and not in `Signout()`?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Signout()` clearing the cookie is simply proactive in case for any reason any of the other moving parts fail.

Comment: If  I `Signout()` on my app, it's impossible to `SignoutCleanup()` there, but I don't have to, because I already `Signed()` out. Is this right?

Comment: Yep, but SignoutCleanup might be called if the user signs out of some other app first.